# Apache reverse proxy before redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a redirect to https on a specific ServerName but before it does the redirect I'd like it to match a Location path and reverse proxy to a separate server rather than redirect to the https URL. Below is how I thought it would work but it seems that it redirects before doing the reverse proxy. Clearly my apache skills are lacking. Maybe, I need two separate VirtualHosts? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    <Location /console>
        ProxyPass http://internal.server.com:8000/console
        ProxyPassReverse http://internal.server.com:8000/console
    </Location>
    <Location />
        Redirect permanent / https://internal.server2.com
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you want the `Redirect` to happen for everything not in `/console`, then?  Or just for the `/` location?

Comment: `Redirect` everything that isn't `/console`. To add to that if it is /console reverse proxy to web application console aka Weblogic console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of letting the `Redirect` config apply for all locations, let's avoid applying it for `/console`.  Remove the `<Location />` section and replace it with:

```
<LocationMatch "!^/console">
    Redirect permanent / https://internal.server2.com/
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: So you are saying I can do this?

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    <Location /console>
        ProxyPass http://internal.server.com:8000/console
        ProxyPassReverse http://internal.server.com:8000/console
    </Location>
    <LocationMatch "!^/console">
        Redirect permanent / https://internal.server2.com
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>

Stupid comments don't handle formatting well.

Comment: @Gareth Right, that should have the `Redirect` take effect for all locations that aren't `/console`